# How to link Hyperledger Fabric smart contract to a front end?

Tags: angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm completely new to Hyperledger and I would like to ask a question. How do we link a smart contract made in Hyperledger Fabric to an Angular Front end ?

I searched over all the web but there were no help ressource... I only found two little 'tutorial' that said to use Hyperledger Composer, however it has been over one year since HC has been deprecated...

If possible could I be explained step by step how to do it please ?

I thank in advance anybody who will take the time to help me !

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way to have an application than interacts with a Hyperledger Fabric Blockchain network, it is doing it through a Backend. Because of that, I recommend you to develop an Backend using the Hyperledger Fabric SDK.

The Fabric SDK allows applications to interact with a Fabric network. It provides a API to submit transactions or query contents with minimal code. In the following [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.html) you have an example that you could use.